# Dielectric Mirrors?

Tags: design

What common electrical product(s) have dielectric mirrors integrated in their design?  I once asked a question on the Physics.SE about alternatives for a Faraday's Cage in order to "shield" leakage of EM radiation, and a person on the site said dielectric mirrors.  I researched and found out how they function, except I do not where to find their application in everyday electronic products.

Comment: He was being facetious. Dielectric mirrors for radio frequencies would not be practical.

Comment: There are EMI absorbing materials available, but they are usually used to supplement a shield/cage, not to replace it. Laird Technologies and Chomerics are two major vendors.

Comment: @Photon - Untrue!  I have used a dielectric mirror at Ku band to provide a polarisation twist in a twist cassegrain antenna.  Admittedly these are macro structures like frequency selective surfaces (FSS) - but perfectly practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want, in order to qualify as *common*, but an entire product area that buys from an area I work in uses them as an essential component in an electronic instrument that finds important use as part of electric system power transformers, like those found in substations. These are fiber-optic thermometers based on phosphor thermometry techniques. We use dichroic mirrors in each and every one of them, and these are essentially dielectric mirrors if I gather your meaning. The wavelengths involved are located within the visible and near visible (from about 400nm to 1100nm, but part of it uses only a very narrow portion of that area.) And there are lots of them used by the power industry, from China to the US. They are also widely used by certain manufacturers using commercial microwave systems for heating their products and where fiber optics doesn't interact with the generated microwaves in the chamber. (If we can get the price down sufficiently, then I think theses would find immediate use in home microwave units since you can easily just *stick* the tip of a fiber into some meat, for example, and set your desired temperature and let it run. But the cost per measurement point remains a little high for that, just yet. Perhaps, though, at least the fact that it might soon be a reality qualifies as a common product?)

Comment: What frequencies are blocked/reflected by the dielectric mirrors in your system?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is included in my non-disclosure so I'd probably avoid exact details. But the system operates with wavelengths that are between 400nm and 1100nm. The mirror reflects light used to charge up the phosphor and passes the fluorescent return which is at a different and fairly narrow wavelength region (when formulated well, anyway.) A splitter arrangement allows the stimulus to share the same fiber as the detector.

Comment: The main point is you're talking about optical frequencies, not RF or microwave.

Comment: It is an electronic product. Visible is also EM. Did the OP ask for RF or microwave? I may have missed reading that.

Comment: No, they didn't ask. But if you read their post history on Physics, that's what they are thinking of.

Comment: I hadn't. Sorry about my ignorance. Do you feel I should just remove the answer? I'm fine with that.

Comment: No, I'd just clarify why this answers the question they asked but maybe not the one they actually want an answer to.

Comment: Okay. I can do that. I'll add a note shortly.